# What's the difference between all of the os.popen() methods?

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I was looking at the [Python documentation](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/module-popen2.html) and saw that there are 4-5 different versions of popen(), e.g. os.popen(), os.popen2(), etc.

Apart from the fact that some include *stderr* while others don't, what are the differences between them and when would you use each one? The documentation didn't really explain it very well.

Answer (score 16):

Jason has it right. To summarize in a way that's easier to see:

- os.popen() -> stdout
- os.popen2() -> (stdin, stdout)
- os.popen3() -> (stdin, stdout, stderr)
- os.popen4() -> (stdin, stdout_and_stderr)

Answer (score 13):

I would recommend to use the `subprocess` module which has all the features that these functions have and more.

Answer (score 10):

popen2 doesn't capture standard error, popen3 does capture standard error and gives a unique file handle for it. Finally, popen4 captures standard error but includes it in the same file object as standard output.